# At startup: access to the "default keyring" is required by 'An Application'

Tags: startup, keyrings

As a newby in Ubuntu land I am a happy user of 20.04LTS....BUT....I am experiencing really weird behavior at automatic logon. There is a window popup stating:

UNLOCK KEYRING

Authentication required

Application wants access to the keyring "default keyring" but it is locked.

Nothing works unless I punch in the password, how can I get rid of this nonsense? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: The complex answer is already posted below with the necessary warnings: *To resolve the issue, you need to **reduce the security of your system** a little more by setting a blank password for the keyring*. The simple and obvious answer is **do NOT use automatic login** (my bold). Even Windows, the dumb OS that used to have it by default, no longer has it and enabling it has been made much harder than in Ubuntu or any mainstream desktop Linux distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not nonsense. This is a request to unlock your keyring, which is stored in an encrypted database. That your passwords are stored in an encrypted file is a safety feature.

Without automatic login, that keyring is automatically unlocked after you entered your user name and password on the login screen. When you enable automatic login, that key is not anymore automatically unlocked. This indeed defeats your purpose of having automatic login - the system needs to request the password as soon as a key from the keyring is needed.

To resolve the issue, you need to reduce the security of your system a little more by setting a blank password for the keyring. You can do that in the utility "Passwords & Keys".

Right-click the "Login" folder and select "Change Password".

[image]

Set your password to nothing.

Comment: Ok, ok, sorry for the aggravated wording, forget it! My passwords and keys (can't get a screenshot in here yet...) only has: "Default keyring", "Private", "GnuPG keys" and "Open SSH keys" plus the "Certificates" section which is most likely not relevant for this purpose. Could you guide me what to do next? Thanks beforehand vanadium.

Comment: OK, I tried to do it with the default keyring and it seems to work. My machine is only for me hence this way forward. No one enters the room it is in without me. OK, let us close this minor thing which led me to understand the ubuntu ways a bit better!